# Is "using std::begin;" a good practice?

Tags: c++, c++11, coding-style, standards

As I have read, `begin(some_vector)` is more standard than `some_vector.begin()` because of array support... and as I know also, the use of `using keyword` is not really desirable behavior. However, I also see lot of code that contains just these two `usings`:

```
using std::begin;
using std::end;
```

Is that considered good or bad practice? Especially when many `begin` and `end` are needed?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> As I have read, `begin(some_vector)` is more standard than `some_vector.begin()` because of array support

It's not "more standard", both are 100% standard. It is more generic, because it works for arrays, but it's not actually very common to have an object and not know whether it's an array or a container type. If you have something that you know is an array then use `std::begin(a)` but if you have something that you know is not an array then there is no advantage to using the form that also works with arrays. If you're in a generic context where you might have either, then `std::begin` works for both cases.

> the use of `using` keyword is not really desirable behavior.

That's debatable. There are very good reasons to avoid using-directives in most contexts (i.e. `using namespace foo`) but the same arguments don't apply to using-declarations that introduce a single name (i.e. `using foo::bar`). For example the recommended way to use `std::swap` is via `using std::swap` so it's certainly not true that the `using` keyword is undesirable in general.

> Is that considered good or bad practice? Especially when many begin and end are needed?

I would say that in general it's a bad idea. As the other answers explain, it allows `begin` and `end` to be found by ADL, but that's not necessarily a good thing. Enabling ADL for `begin` and `end` can cause problems, that's why we changed range-based `for` at the last minute to *not* use `using std::begin; using std::end;` to avoid ambiguities, see [N3257](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2011/n3257.pdf) for the details.

Comment: Range-based for do use ADL for begin/end if all else fail, no?

Comment: @T.C. the last resort for range-based `for` is actually a weird lookup that exists nowhere else (it _only_ uses associated namespaces, not other names in scope!) It's not equivalent to `using std::begin; auto b = begin(range);` so `std::begin` will only get found if `std` is an associated namespace (in contrast to how [swappable.requirements] says `std::swap` is a candidate for overload resolution). It's not necessary for `std::begin` to be a candidate, because `std::begin(r)` only works if `r.begin()` is valid, and if that's valid then bullet (1.2) of range-based `for` would have used it.

Comment: @T.C. I've changed the last sentence of my answer to be more accurate about the change, as you're right that some form of ADL might still happen. The part that's relevant to this question is that it doesn't use `using std::begin; using std::end;` because that is what caused problems.

Comment: But `begin()` and `end()` free functions can be also used to add iteration functionality to some external classes which do not provide `.begin` and `.end` methods.

Comment: And then you say about `swap` being a customization point, what are other things intended to be customization points in standard library? Is there a complete list of them anywhere?

Comment: @IlyaPopov, no, there is no official list, and no unofficial one I know of. `swap` is _definitely_ a customization point. `begin` and `end` _kind of_ are, because of how range-based `for` uses them (but I consider that a mistake, and I'm not sure they should be considered customization points). Arguably `size`, `empty` etc. from [N4017](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4017.htm) could be customization points too, if people use them that way ... I think those functions are mistakes too, and should **not** used as be customization points. They should be used qualified.

Comment: @IlyaPopov, defining a customization point (i.e. a function that is meant to be used unqualified to find other overloads via ADL) is a **very** risky thing to do. It makes a name like `swap` almost a keyword, because **any** function called `swap` can now potentially be found even if it's safely confined to some namespace. Adding more customization points with extremely common names like "size" and "empty" is a very risky thing to do, we have no idea how many people have used those names for functions that do different things, and it's risky to suddenly start looking up common names via ADL.

Comment: @IlyaPopov, finally, you can also add iteration functionality to an existing class by using a thin adaptor class that has `begin()` and `end()` members that simply forward to some other member of the class being adapted. So if you have a class with `First()` and `Last()` members you would do `for (auto i : make_rangelike(c))` where that function creates the adaptor class that stores `&c` and its `begin()` calls `m_wrapped->First()` and its `end()` calls `m_wrapped->Last()`. This might be safer than adapting the class by adding free functions to be found by ADL.

Comment: @JonathanWakely, thank you for explanation! I used to use `using std::begin` thing, but from now on I probably will prefer not doing this.

Answer (score 7):

It can be helpful for `ADL` help. Something like:

```
template<typename T, typename F>
void apply(T& v, const F& f)
{
   using std::begin;
   using std::end;
   std::for_each(begin(v), end(v), f);
}
```

So, than we just can call `apply` with types, that have `begin/end` functions and classic C arrays.

In other case it's actually okay to use `using` directive in source file, in little scope and so on, but it's bad to use in header.

Comment: +1 very nice trick, however I am a bit in doubt about its readability because I should make one for for_each and one for max_element and so on

Comment: @HumamHelfawi `for_each` is just example. And `apply` is just example really. Such ADL helper was/is very common with `swap` function.

Comment: Not only is it not so useful because `std::begin` and `std::end` probably already do the right thing, this can cause your code to fail to compile because you might find that e.g. `boost::begin` and `std::begin` are ambiguous.

Comment: swap` is a customisation point and is intended to be used with `using std::swap` and allowing other definitions to be found by ADL, it's not clear to me that `begin` and `end` should be used that way.

Answer (score 5):

> Is that considered good or bad practice?

This depends a lot on the context; I think the answer is equally applicable to the more general question of introducing names via a `using`. Limit the scope of the use of `using` makes for more readable code (such as function level scope); use it as required, use it with care.

A particularly interesting case here revolves around ADL.

```
template <class Container>
void func(Container& c)
{
  std::for_each(begin(c), end(c), /* some functor*/);
}
```

ADL is already in play, since if the container is from the `std` namespace, the `std::begin` and `std::end` will be found. If the container is from a custom namespace, `begin` and `end` functions can be found in that namespace (for this discussion, I assume the container provider has also provided these).

If the container is a normal C-style array, the array form `std::begin(T (&array)[N])` will not be found since the C-style array is not the `std` namespace. Introducing a `using std::begin` here allows the code to be used for arrays and containers.

```
template <class Container>
void func(Container& c)
{
  using std::begin; // if c is an array, the function will still compile
  using std::end;
  std::for_each(begin(c), end(c), /* some functor*/);
}
// ...
int a[100];
func(a); // works as expected
```

[**Demo**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/113d61eebe0d0d77).

Answer (score 1):

It depends. Using declarations (and, far more, using directives) in header files are heavily discouraged. However, if inside the body of a function you use a lot of times one or several functions from another namespace, a using declaration / directives (put inside the body of the function, so limited to its scope) can make the code more readable.