# Why is argument-dependent lookup (ADL) choosing class method instead of more fiting free function?

Tags: c++, c++11, class-method, argument-dependent-lookup, non-member-functions

According to [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/adl), in **Argument-dependent** lookups

> function names are looked up in the namespaces of their arguments in
> addition to the scopes and namespaces considered by the usual
> unqualified name lookup.

However, why is it then that in the following example in function A::member_function() the *class-method* begin() is choosen which 1) takes 0 arguments and 2) isn't even in the namespace of std::vector, the argument of the function? Shouldn't ADL go to the namespace of the arguments (which is std for vector) and choose the free function std::begin()?

```
#include <unordered_map>
#include <vector>


class A
{
public:
    using value_t = std::unordered_map<int, char>;
public:
    void member_function();
    value_t::iterator begin() { return map_.begin(); }

private:
    value_t map_;
};


void A::member_function() 
{
    std::vector<int> hello;
    auto it = begin(hello);
}
```

I'm also happy for a workaround if this is really the way ADL works.

Answer (score 2):

ADL is not done if ordinary unqualified name lookup finds a class member.

You can avoid this issue with a using-declaration, so that unqualified name lookup is guaranteed to always result in `std::begin`:

```
using std::begin;
auto it = begin(hello);
```

This will always find `std::begin`, but also do ADL to find other `begin` overloads.

You can also use a qualified call `std::begin(hello);` which will forward correctly to the `.begin` member of the argument, if possible, but will not do any ADL.

In C++20 there is `std::ranges::begin`, which can be used instead of the method above. It is a customization point object and will forward to the correct `begin` for the argument more generally, either to a  member if possible or via ADL.

Comment: Ty, but this way I always have to write `using std::begin` into every method that uses std::begin()? That also seems tedious..

Comment: @glades You probably just want `std::begin(hello);` or `std::ranges::begin(hello);` and not bother with ADL at all. Discussion on whether or not to use `using std::begin;` followed by unqualified call [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31604984/is-using-stdbegin-a-good-practice/31607065).